# In how many different ways can persons A,B,C,D and E be seated around two equal round tables so that no table remains empty?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, stirling-numbers

Persons A and E never sit at the same table.

I'm guessing you could describe this in terms of Stirling numbers but I'm basically lost from there.

My guess is that it's s(5,2) - the number of occurrences in which both A and E occur.

Comment: How many seats do the tables have?

Comment: @Zuy We assume that everyone can be seated properly in an arbitrary number of seats.

Comment: Not many tables and not all that many people ... did you just try and exhaust all possibilities? Indeed, can you show us a little bit of your efforts, please?

Comment: @Bram28 I've edited my question. Is it better now?

Comment: If person $A$ and $E$ never sit on the same table then seat them on two tables in $2$ ways. Then you only have to seat remaining $3$ people in $2^3$ ways, right? May be I don't follow your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider case $n$: First table has $n$ occupied places, and second table has $5-n$ occupied places.

Number of ways to choose $n$ persons for first table is $\binom{5}{n}$.

Number of ways to seat $n$ persons around round table is $(n-1)!$. To prove it, we number occupied seats starting from seat occupied by first person (we can use alphabet rule to select first person). There are $n-1$ candidates for second seat, $n-2$ candidates for third seat, and so on.

Total number of ways for case $n$ is $A_n=\binom{5}{n}\cdot(n-1)!\cdot(4-n)!$. Last factor is number of ways for second table.

$$A_n=\frac{5!(n-1)!(4-n)!}{n!(5-n)!}=\frac{120}{n(5-n)}$$

Total number of ways is $$\sum_{n=1}^4 A_n=100$$